# Projects built on each other

Tags: git

I'm developing in PHP, using the Kohana framework (the question has nothing to do with PHP or Kohana, so just keep reading).

This means that I start all my projects by cloning the Kohana's repo from Github, and start building my app.

### Step 1: The base app

However, to make my life easier I created a repository - let's name it `base-app`, where I personalized the framework for my needs.
Basically I created the folder structure for static files, added some JS and CSS files which I'll use in all my future projects (like normalize.css, jquery.js, my JS framework, etc). I also registered some submodules I wrote, and pushed this new repo to a remote.
Great! Now I have a base app (I like to call it *skeleton*), I can clone everytime I start a new project.

### Step 2: Authentication

In most apps we also need an authentication system. So I continued developing.
I created an `auth` submodule to help me with that, but I also needed to create some views, controllers also JS and CSS files (which I can't just put in a submodule) for the `login`, `recover-password`, `reset-password`, etc. pages. Named the repo `base-app-auth`, and pushed to a remote.

Great! Now I have a new repository: `base-app-auth` based on the `base-app`, I can clone when I want to create an app with a login system (controllers, models, views, js, css) already implemented.

### Step 3: Accounts & Payments

In at least two of my future projects (and maybe many others) I will also need a solution for managing accounts (subscriptions) and payments.
So I continued developing. Based on the `base-app-auth` I implemented a solution for accepting payments (through PayPal) and managing subscriptions. This repository also has new views, controllers, models but also new css and js files. (No, I can't simply put them in a submodule).

Great! Now I have a repository I can clone when I want to create a new app with a login system and accounts/payments management already implemented.

### The problem:

The problem is that now I have 3 repositories. Keeping them in sync is a pain in the ***.

I mean, when I fix an error in the `base-app`, or develop a new feature in it, I also want the two other repositories to have these changes. So I have to clone the two others and pull the changes from `base-app`, then push them back to remote.

I'm looking for a better solution.

### A possible solution:

A possible solution, I can think off, is to have all the 3 "apps" in a single repository (because actually it's a single app) on different branches. So when I start a project I clone the repository and decide which branch to checkout.

If I don't need the authentication and the account & payment management feature I checkout the `base-app` branch. If I need authentication but don't need accounts & payments I checkout the `base-app-auth` branch, and so on.

Is this a good solution? Is there a better one? What is a good way to manage these "cascading" projects in Git?

Comment: Have you looked at submodules?
http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: Ahah!  You have just recreated the days before the git people implemented `git submodule`, which is the technology to use.  I highly recommend it.

Comment: @Ethan Yes I do. However they don't solve this problem. Please see my previous comment. Thanks.

Comment: @Kzqai No, I didn't :)

Comment: I use submodules when it's possible. However, they doesn't solve all the problems. For example in base-app-auth I have javascript and css files that must be placed under APP_PATH/static/js and APP_PATH/static/css. I also have PHP files that must be placed under APP_PATH/application/classes/Controllers or APP_PATH/application/classes/Models. How you solve this with submodules? As I know, all files from a submodule go to specified directory, but I need the files from "submodule" distributed in multiple existing folders.